# Visual Basics Loan Calculator Using Functions

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

I need to build a Loan Calculator that uses functions to provide the values, for the text boxes, based on what radio button is clicked. Then i need to use a Sub to report the result with a label.

I think i am started off in the right direction but i have no background in vb so please bear with me.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Payment As Double
    Dim Nper As Double
    Dim LoanIRate As Double
    Dim LoanDuration As Integer
    Dim LoanAmount As Integer


    If rdbmp1.Checked Then
        Payment = Pmt(LoanIRate, LoanDuration, -LoanAmount, 0, )
        TextBox4.Text = Payment.ToString("#.00")
    End If
    If rdbamt1.Checked Then
        LoanAmount = PV(LoanIRate / 1200, LoanDuration, -Payment)
        TextBox1.Text = Payment.ToString("#.00")
    End If
    If rdbir1.Checked Then
        LoanIRate = 1200 * Rate(LoanDuration, Payment - LoanAmount)
        TextBox2.Text = Payment.ToString("#.00")
    End If
    If rdbdl1.Checked Then
        LoanDuration = Nper(LoanIRate / 1200, Payment, -LoanAmount)
        TextBox3.Text = Payment.ToString("#.00")
    End If
End Sub
```

At the moment the only calculation that is working for me correctly is the monthly payment, all of the others have build errors.

Comment: What are the build errors?

Comment: When trying to calculate LoanIrate i get an error saying "argument not specified for parameter PV", and when trying to calculate LoanDuration using NPER i get "Expression is not an array or method".

Answer (score 0):

`PV` is a custom method, most likely defined in your project on by one of your libraries.  You are currently passing it three parameters, but it apparently must expect more than that.  Since I don't know what parameters it expects, I can't answer what else needs to be passed.  If you right click on the `PV` method name and select the **Go To Definition** option, you will be able to see what the proper parameters are for that method.

The second error message that you mentioned is trying to explain that `Nper` is not a method, but you are trying to call it as if it was one.  It may actually be the name of a real method, but you have defined a local variable as `Dim Nper As Double`, so it thinks you are referring to that variable name rather than the method.  To fix that, you should probably just rename or remove that local variable.